# Using async/await with event handler in loop

Tags: javascript, loops, promise, async-await, event-handling

i can use promise.all solute the requirement, just like:

```
Promise.all(pics.map(e => new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  var img=new Image();
  img.addEventListener("load",() => { //i need all event handler finish
    imageonload(e);  
    resolve();
  },false);
  img.onerror=(err) => reject(err);
  img.src=e.src; //this call the event handler          
}))).then(() => {       
  // here do something when the event handler finish all.
}))
```

My question is can we use async/await rewrite the code, because I don/t like brackets hell.

Comment: Sure. you can change it to `await Promise.all(....); /* here do something when the event handler finish all */`. The context must be an `async` function of course.

Comment: `Promise.all()` method also returns a single Promise that fulfils when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled. So, you can use `await Promise.all(....)` inside an async function.

Comment: You can use `await` to replace the `then` call, yes. You cannot use `await` to replace the `new Promise` call. If you don't like that many nested brackets, refactor the image loading into a named helper function.

Comment: thanks, @FelixKling, that can make it clear more.

Comment: @palaѕн I don/t need the event handler success, I just want it finish. after all handler finish and then to do something.

Comment: @Bergi, now is 2020, does not we have some solution just like es10/11/12/13?  and this is not the same question, you just say async/await can/t use in this question. but your question can be solve easy.

Comment: @马长昆michaelbergman Nothing about async/await syntax changed in the last 3 years. I'm not sure what you expect. At best, there would be a new web api that replaces the `load` event with a native promise, but the answer to the general question about "*using async/await with event handler*" is still the same.